# Ternary relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

In my Laravel project, I need to use a ternary relationship, so I have three tables.

**Questionnaire**

```
Schema::create('questionnaires', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    $table->string('Quanti');
    $table->date('date_heure');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Responses**

```
Schema::create('reponses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    $table->string('libelle_reponse', 50);
    $table->integer('ordre');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Questions**

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id');
        $table->string('libelle_question', 50);
        $table->integer('ordre');
        $table->string('graphique', 50);
        $table->foreignId('type_id')->constrained('type', 'id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And finally, I have the pivot table.

```
Schema::create('questionnaire_reponse_question', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('reponse_id')->constrained('reponses', 'id');;
            $table->foreignId('question_id')->constrained('questions', 'id');;
            $table->foreignId('questionnaire_id')->constrained('questionnaires', 'id');;
            $table->primary(['reponse_id', 'questionnaire_id', 'question_id']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

But now I need to create the relationships between my different models by using the pivot table; I've found a solution that works, so it's to create another model as a pivot model, but I want to know if an all-make solution exists.
Here is my mcd if it can help you better understand my problem print.sc/HpW8pQpyAO6V

Comment: See this Medium Article for an explanation of how to use Pivot tables though models. [Article](https://medium.com/@miladev95/laravel-pivot-table-15c69d517a83)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having problems? Have you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)? Specifically the bits that say how you can specify table names in relationship methods?

Answer (score 0):

- Relationships between your Laravel models using the provided tables and pivot table, you can define the relationships directly in your models. Laravel Eloquent ORM makes it convenient to work with relationships.
- Here are the relationships you can define in your models

Questionnaire Model

```
class Questionnaire extends Model
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'questionnaire_reponse_question', 'questionnaire_id', 'question_id')
                    ->withPivot('reponse_id');
    }

    public function responses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Response::class, 'questionnaire_reponse_question', 'questionnaire_id', 'reponse_id')
                    ->withPivot('question_id');
    }
}
```

Question Model

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function questionnaires()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Questionnaire::class, 'questionnaire_reponse_question', 'question_id', 'questionnaire_id')
                    ->withPivot('reponse_id');
    }

    public function responses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Response::class, 'questionnaire_reponse_question', 'question_id', 'reponse_id')
                    ->withPivot('questionnaire_id');
    }
}
```

Response Model

```
class Response extends Model
{
    public function questionnaires()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Questionnaire::class, 'questionnaire_reponse_question', 'reponse_id', 'questionnaire_id')
                    ->withPivot('question_id');
    }

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'questionnaire_reponse_question', 'reponse_id', 'question_id')
                    ->withPivot('questionnaire_id');
    }
}
```

- With these relationships, you can easily retrieve related data through the pivot table. For example, to get all responses for a specific questionnaire

```
$questionnaire = Questionnaire::find($questionnaireId);
$responses = $questionnaire->responses;
```

- Make sure to replace $questionnaireId with the actual ID you're working with.